# Ubuntu 22.04 bluetooth cannot search other devices

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

I have my phone's bluetooth turned on and am using a bluetooth mouse

```
~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 4C:03:4F:6D:C7:4C Discovering: yes
```

This is my virtual machine's mac address, so it doesn't find other devices.
I have used `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git` to install firmware.

I used `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[    1.123863] usb 2-1: Product: Virtual Bluetooth Adapter
[    4.630717] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.630739] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.630740] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.637167] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.637192] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.637196] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.267398] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.267401] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.267403] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.305505] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.305510] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.305513] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    9.830430] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639633.053:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1082 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    9.901955] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639633.121:71): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1076 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    9.940074] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639633.157:72): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1076 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   10.416810] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639633.637:73): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2012 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   10.428443] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639633.653:74): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2013 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   10.430256] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639633.653:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2012 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   11.042666] audit: type=1400 audit(1665639634.265:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2105 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
```

I didn't find what file is missing. It's just cannot find other devices, what I should do?

Comment: Does that Bluetooth device support having multiple devices attached at the same time?

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem. Are you trying to connect a mouse or a phone?

Comment: Well, I can't find any device when I turn on Bluetooth in the "setting". If ubuntu cannot find the device, how could I connect them?